# Microsoft Graph sending chat message with fetch() BadRequest

Tags: post, microsoft-graph-api, fetch-api

According to the graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages), this is the form for POSTing a chat message.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:2da4c29f6d7041eca70b638b43d45437@thread.v2/messages
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
     "content": "Hello world"
  }
}
```

However, when I make the following fetch request, the returned JSON indicates the body is malformed. Exact ID & token redacted.

```js
fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{CHAT-ID}/messages",
    {
        method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer {ACCESS-TOKEN}",
                "Host": "graph.microsoft.com",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "content": "Message" })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```

```
{
  error: {
    code: 'BadRequest',
    message: 'Missing body content',

...
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `body` property in your request. The `body` in this case is a property of [chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource.

Try to change `JSON.stringify({ "content": "Message" })` to `JSON.stringify({"body": { "content": "Message" }})` it will ensure that the request body will have the correct structure.

```
fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{CHAT-ID}/messages",
    {
        method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer {ACCESS-TOKEN}",
                "Host": "graph.microsoft.com",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({"body": { "content": "Message" }})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```